# Writing code for a text based game

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a method that removes an item from the inventory. It should delete the item from the string array, then shuffle the remaining items to the front of the array. However, it doesn't work. no error is thrown, but the item is still there.

```
    public static int removeFromInventory(String object, String[] items, int numItems) {

  int objectSlot = 0;
  boolean objFound = false; 

  if(numItems>0){
    for(int i=0;i>numItems ;i++){
      if(object.equalsIgnoreCase(items[i])){
        objectSlot = i;
        numItems++;
        objFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(objFound){
      items[objectSlot]=null;
      System.out.print(items[objectSlot]);
      for(int n=objectSlot; n < items.length -1;n++){
        items[n] = items[n+1];
      }
      items[items.length -1] = null;
      objFound = false;
    }
  }

  return numItems;
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Oh, and don't forget to ask a question.

Comment: Ach, wouldn't be the first time I've missed that. I need to up my font size.

Comment: Also there is no need for `numItems` parameter, since you have `items.length`.

Comment: @Spork: I notice you corrected the question. Can you confirm that the `>` was actually the problem? If so, please don't do that - it makes the answers no longer relevant to the question.

Comment: I really should delete this and resubmit it, because I have a whole new problem now. See my response to Mac.

Comment: @Spork: having a new problem isn't a reason to delete *any* question - this question's still valid, whether you've got a new problem or not. Also, since you accepted my answer, I'm assuming the `>` was, in fact, the problem - as such, I've rolled back your correction (as per my previous comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for(int i = 0; i > numItems; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) // Note the < instead of the >
```

With it as you currently have it, your first loop will never execute, and hence your item will never be found.

Note that you can also eliminate the need for the `numItems` parameter by only searching through the array until you hit the first `null` entry. Not a big issue, but potentially makes things a bit simpler. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.length && items[i] != null; i++)
```

Comment: That worked! But now I have another problem. My inventory is filling up with nulls. Is there an alternative to null to signify an empty slot? What are empty spaces in new arrays "called"?

Comment: @Spork: I don't think that would be as a result of these changes. I'm guessing the problem's elsewhere. When do the nulls appear? When using this method or a different one?

Comment: The numItems++ should've been numItems--. Now everything seems to be working, with the exception that when I add something to my inventory it prints null<object> instead of object, but I have no clue where to even start with that one.

Comment: Solved it all now, had an extra debugging print in there. Thanks for the help and the shortcut!

Comment: No worries! Happy to be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

First you have a try to change the following code

```
 if(numItems>0){
    for(int i=0;i>numItems ;i++){
```

to

```
 if(numItems>0){
    for(int i=0;i<numItems ;i++){
```

Make a change and go ahead.